# Mapbox Map for first time users with no connectivity

Tags: swift3, mapbox

I need help with displaying a default mapView to first-time users with no network connectivity. Then as soon as the network is available, load the mapView using the styleURL.

The latter part is taken care of, however, I'm still struggling with displaying the mapView for the first-time users using the local styles I downloaded from Mapbox:

```
let localURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json")

if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: styleURL)
    ...
} else {
    mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: localURL)
    ...
}
```

Am I missing something?